# Abacus flight booking api, after creating PNR there is a possibility to append segment in booking through EnhancedAirBook api

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I want to ask about abacus flight booking api, after creating PNR there is a possibility to append segment in booking through EnhancedAirBook api b/c I saw in api we can pass the PNR no. I used it but not working any more, I am using enhancedairbook 2.0 version. if some body tried it plz share the request and response.

Comment: Can you please share code that you've tried? Please also check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the provided examples available today on Dev Studio under the Service Description?

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/orchestrated_air_booking